# Multi-property "transactions" in Core Data / NSManagedObject / NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

Is it possible to set multiple properties of an NSManagedObject and have the NSFetchedResultsController call controllerDidChangeContent: only once?

In other words, is it possible to say something like:

```
[managedObject beginChanges];
[managedObject setPropertyA:@"Foo"];
[managedObject setPropertyB:@"Bar"];
[managedObject commitChanges];
```

and then have the NSFetchedResultsController call controllerDidChangeContent: (and the other methods) only one time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm solving it now by creating another `NSManagedObjectContext`, that acts as 'scratch pad' for the changes. Then when all edits have been done, it's merged back into the other context, using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`. There is a sample project called CoreDataBooks showing how this works.

Answer (score 0):

While definitely not a perfect solution, you could add a method to your managed object class that takes the two new property values, and works much like your code above.